# Change values in one dataframe if values appear in another dataframe based on one column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe, "big" and "correction":

big:

```
>>>ID    class    fruit
0  1     medium   banana
1  2     medium   banana
2  3     high     peach
3  4     low      nuts
4  5     low      banana
```

and correction:

```
>>> ID  class  time  fruit
0   2  medium   17   melon
1   5  high     19   oranges
```

I want to fix the table "big" according to information in table correction. in order to get the following table:

```
>>>ID    class    fruit
0  1     medium   banana
1  2     medium   **melon**
2  3     high     peach
3  4     low      nuts
4  5     **high** **oranges**
```

as you can see, the starred values "fixed" according to the correction tabl, on the ID field.

I thought to use for nested loop but I believe there are better ways to get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `df.update` after aligning the indexes of both dataframes:

```
big.set_index("ID",inplace=True)
big.update(correction.set_index("ID")
```

---

```
big = big.reset_index() #ifyou want `ID` as a column back
print(big)

   ID   class    fruit
0   1  medium   banana
1   2  medium    melon
2   3    high    peach
3   4     low     nuts
4   5    high  oranges
```

Comment: @is possible to determine which column I want to change? (for example to write in the code that I want to change only the class and fruit in df big, from the column class and fruit from correction (to be sure it doesn't change other things)

Comment: @Reut yes , you can take a subset of the correction dataframe : `big.update(correction.set_index("ID")[['class','fruit']])`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
corr_df.set_index('ID').combine_first(big_df.set_index('ID'))
```

Comment: but there are no null values. Does this work for duplicates?

Comment: Duplicate ID, no.  This will not work.  You will need to either use merge or update and create some sort of helper column to handle duplicate ID if they have different data for each subsequent occurance of that ID.  In this case, we are using ID as a unique identifier for each record in both dataframes.